# C# - Method to Create Instances of Different Types

Tags: c#, factory

I've created a method that acts as a factory to roll out the type of connection I need. In this case, I'm possibly instantiating types `SqlConnection` and `PrincipalContext`, and returning that instance. The method takes in a single parameter, type `Object`. If the parameter value is of the specified type above, it will create an instance of that object. My issue is the return type of the method is `Object`, so a cast is required when the method is called.

An example would be:

```
SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection();
SqlConnection sqlCon = (SqlConnection)ConnectionFactory.RolloutConnectionType(connection2);
```

And the RolloutConnectionType method:

```
public static Object RolloutConnectionType(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        if (obj is PrincipalContext) {//create new PrincipalContext
            string user, pass, domain;
            domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAdomain"];
            user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAuser"];
            pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SApass"];

            obj = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain + ".mydomain.ca", "CN=MyCN,DC=myDC,DC=ca", user, pass);
        } else if (obj is SqlConnection) {//create new SqlConnection
            string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            obj = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I think I'm on the right track with this, but it seems very messy and likely redundant with an instance required to create an instance - `connection2` to create and return `obj` in `RolloutConnectionType`. It works, but I don't like how it works. Is what I'm attempting possible? Are there other avenues I could pursue?

Comment: So you're passing a factory method an instance which is then redefined as a new instance? Not sounding like a factory anymore...

Comment: Why not just have two overloads that accept the different types directly and correspondingly return those types? No casting required.

Comment: @BradChristie Admittedly this is quite messy. More to the point of if something along these lines is possible. What I have posted in the OP is more of an example and not something I would ever use in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick with the factory pattern, you should be looking at something like the following:

```
public interface Factory<T>
{
    T Create();
}

public class PrincipalContextFactory : IFactory<PrincipalContext>
{
    public PrinicipalContext Create()
    {
        // return new PrincipalContext(...);
    }
}

public class SqlConnectionFactory : IFactory<SqlConnection>
{
    public SqlConnection Create()
    {
        // return new SqlConnection(...);
    }
}
```

Your factory shouldn't need anything more than to return a new instance of what you're after. You could go generics (`Create<T>()`), but now you're creating a bunch of edge cases for models not a `PrinicpalContext` or `SqlConnection`.

Comment: This is actually quite useful and leads into some new possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: Like your version better :)

Comment: @DRapp: Could implement `YourFactory : IFactory<PrincipalContext>, IFactory<SqlConnection>`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have your factory class with static methods of each thing your are trying to create and have each method return its own properly type-cast object

```
public static class YourFactory
{
   public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
   {
      string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                          .ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
      return new SqlConnection(connStr);
   }

   public static PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext()
   {
        string user, pass, domain;
        domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAdomain"];
        user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAuser"];
        pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SApass"];

        return new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain + ".mydomain.ca",
                 "CN=MyCN,DC=myDC,DC=ca", user, pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I have implemented, but was looking to have them combined into one roll-out method. Obviously we can't have multiple return types, `SqlConnection` and `PrincipalContext`, hence the return type being `Object`. Is this possible? Or would the recommendation be sticking to what you have above?

Comment: @DrewKennedy: Can't have the best of both worlds. You either have `Object` and cast it, or use a stringly-typed method (albeit return type or using generics).

Comment: @BradChristie Ahh okay. Was hoping there was some ninja way of doing it that I may have overlooked. I appreciate your feedback. Your answer isn't wrong per se so I'll give you an up.

Comment: @DrewKennedy To be clear, if you owned the object you could implement your own `implicit`/`explicit` cast operator and cast it, but that's not very elegant.